# Displaying data from database in a Dropdown Menu

Tags: php, html, database, drop-down-menu

I have successfully got my php code to connect to my database and retreieve data and display it. I am now trying to take this data and display it in a dropdown menu, however when I do this the dropdown menu displays the correct number of options that correlates with the data in the database(ie. it gives three options if there is 3 values in the db). But it doesn't display the text all the options are blank. Any ideas as to why it is not displaying the text?

```
<?php
$dbhost= 'Host IP';
$dbuser ='My Username';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$sql='SELECT event_id FROM events';
mysql_select_db('db_name');
$retval= mysql_query($sql, $conn);

echo'<select name=dropdown value=', '>Dropdown</option>';
while($r= mysql_fetch_array($retval))
{
echo "<option value={$r["event_id"]}>{$r["events"]}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxHYf.png

The link is what the menu currently returns

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not select events from database. You need to select all(*) or required columns by its name in the query .

Change your query:

```
$sql='SELECT event_id FROM events';
```

to :

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM events';
```

You also need to take option value inside quotes.

Change this line inside loop:

```
echo "<option value={$r["event_id"]}>{$r["events"]}</option>";
```

to:

```
echo "<option value=\"{$r['event_id']}\">{$r['events']}</option>";
```

Comment: @user3067182 : did you try this?

Comment: did you get `print_r($r);` inside loop to see what you have got from database?

Comment: Just tried it and it returned nothing actually. Not sure why as my php block before it works fine getting data from the same database. Back to the drawing board!

Comment: check your column names(event_id,events) with database and inside loop are exact same or not

Answer (score 2):

try it like this (change your query to `select *`)

```
echo '<option value='.$r["event_id"].'>'.$r["events"].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just selecting `event_id` from the table. So, `$r["events"]` is always empty.
Select the title field, too.

```
<?php
$dbhost= 'Host IP';
$dbuser ='My Username';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$sql='SELECT event_id,event_title FROM events';
mysql_select_db('db_name');
$retval= mysql_query($sql, $conn);

echo'<select name=dropdown value=', '>Dropdown</option>';
while($r= mysql_fetch_array($retval))
{
echo "<option value={$r["event_id"]}>{$r["event_title"]}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

I assumed, that the field name is "event_title".